# Fried eggs and boiled eggs, which is better for muscle build up?

Tags: food

I want to build a muscle body, and heard I should eat eggs, but I don't know if I should eat fried eggs or boiled eggs, is there any suggestion?

Comment: Fried eggs, will include the olive oil used to fry them in, thus will provide more calories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on what kind of diet you follow , Fried Eggs doesn't make much difference . If you compare both Fried and boiled ,both will give 6gms of protein, 1gm of carbohydrate .But the Boiled on differs in Fat and Calories content  ,as it gives you 70gm calories where as Fried one will give you 90 and the fat content will also differs from 5.3 to 6.8 .

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on whether or not you want a chunky muscle body or a lean and ripped muscle body.  I am not a body builder, nor have I ever trained to be one, but I have skimmed through the diets that some of them follow and I don't ever recall seeing fried eggs on those menus.  In fact, typically they do eat a lot of eggs in the form of egg whites, but little to no egg yolk.  If you're really serious about developing a muscle body, I recommend you train yourself to start incorporating egg whites into your diet.  You can even buy them by the carton at most grocery stores.  I've listed a few links to some articles that may interest you on this topic:

**Ava Cowan's Diet Plan (you'll see egg whites on the menu):**

http://www.fitflex.com/ava-cowan-pics.html

She doesn't describe how she prepares the eggs, but I doubt she fries her egg whites in butter.

**Recipes from Monica Brant (many include egg whites):**

http://www.bodybuilding.com/fun/monica4.htm

**Lots of ideas here that don't involve frying:**

http://www.bodybuilding.com/fun/7-ways-to-cook-eggs.html

**I myself am a big fan of the Egg White Frittata.  Below is a recipe I've never tried, but it looks quite good:**

http://www.foodiecrush.com/2015/02/spinach-and-mushroom-egg-white-frittata/

You'll find a lot of new and interesting diet strategies out there these days, but you asked about eggs, so I'll stop here.

As always, exercise (and diet) at your own risk and see a doctor if you're concerned about your health or the diet you're about to follow.  If you decide to stop eating fried eggs, with or without the yolk, I think most doctors would be okay with that.  For further proof that frying may not be all that healthy, you may want to read this article here: http://www.hsph.harvard.edu/news/hsph-in-the-news/eating-fried-foods-tied-to-increased-risk-of-diabetes-and-heart-disease/.